# SML - Why does my code return a weird reference?

Tags: reference, linked-list, sml

I'm trying to write a function that uses references and destructively updates a sorted linked list while inserting a value.
My code is as follows:

```
Control.Print.printDepth := 100;
datatype 'a rlist = Empty | RCons of 'a * (('a rlist) ref);

fun insert(comp: (('a * 'a) -> bool), toInsert: 'a, lst: (('a rlist) ref)): unit =
    let
         val r = ref Empty;
         fun insert' comp toInsert lst =
                    case !lst of
                         Empty => r := (RCons(toInsert, ref Empty))
                         | RCons(x, L) => if comp(toInsert, x) then r := (RCons(toInsert, lst))
                                          else ((insert(comp,toInsert,L)) ; (r := (RCons(x, L))));
    in
         insert' comp toInsert lst ; lst := !r
    end;

val nodes = ref (RCons(1, ref (RCons(2, ref (RCons(3, ref (RCons(5, ref Empty))))))));
val _ = insert((fn (x,y) => if x <= y then true else false), 4, nodes);
!nodes;
```

!nodes returns

```
val it = RCons (1,ref (RCons (2,ref (RCons (3,ref (RCons (4,%1)) as %1)))))
 : int rlist
```

when it should return

```
val it = RCons (1,ref (RCons (2,ref (RCons (3,ref (RCons (4, ref (RCons(5, ref Empty))))))))
: int rlist
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that your code is buggy, and has returned a cyclic list, where the tail of `ref(RCons(4, ...))` is actually the same `ref(RCons(4, ...))` again.

Remarks:

1. You don't need to pass `comp` and `toInsert` to the inner function, they are already in scope.
2. `if C then true else false` is the same as writing just `C`.
3. In SML, you typically use comparison functions of type `t * t -> order`, and they are predefined in the library, see e.g. `Int.compare`.
4. About 70% of the parentheses in your code are redundant.
5. You don't normally want to use such a data structure in ML.
6. If you absolutely have to, here is how I would write the code:

   ```
   datatype 'a rlist' = Empty | Cons of 'a * 'a rlist
   withtype 'a rlist  = 'a rlist' ref

   fun insert compare x l =
       case !l of
         Empty => l := Cons(x, ref Empty)
       | Cons(y, l') =>
           case compare(x, y) of
             LESS => l := Cons(x, ref(!l))
           | EQUAL => ()  (* or whatever else you want to do in this case *)
           | GREATER => insert compare x l'
   ```

Comment: I fixed 1. and 2., for 3. I need to follow my prof's type signature and he said it has to be 'a * 'a -> bool.

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
| RCons(x, L) => if comp(toInsert, x) then r := (RCons(toInsert, lst))
```

to

```
| RCons(x, L) => if comp(toInsert, x) then r := (RCons(toInsert, ref(!lst)))
```